# How to create watch-only wallet on a server with a full node?

Tags: wallet, security, full-node, watch-only

**Given:** there're online shops and a server with a full BTC node that I plan to run. I'll be using a full node to monitor incomming transcations thus receiving payments in an automatic manner. Only. Namely, a customer will see a result of his payment in, at most, 10 minutes.

**Question:** How can I create a wallet that's receive-/watch- only, that'll have to stored on a server?

That is, if a server gets broken into, a hacker won't be able to do anything with a wallet he steals, later on. But I will be because a private key will be stored on my local computer. I'll login into a server once a week and withdraw the funds from a wallet.

--

I don't consider any other - paid, free, open source - ready solutions. The question isn't about a solution to receive BTC payments.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install Bitcoin core and import an address as watch only, then you can track all transactions.

Comment: how import an address as watch only?

Comment: [@kosmosu05](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/109589/kosmosu05) Very simple, into console type `importaddress "address"`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following article can help you:
https://bitcoinelectrum.com/creating-a-watch-only-wallet/

Comment: that doesn't help me